# Форматировать строку в объект Date(), js

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть строка такого формата - 22.06.17 . Каким образом можно из нее сделать объект Date ?

`var new_date = new Date('22.06.17');` - не работает

Comment: У вас не тот формат: [смотреть](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var date_str = '22.06.17';
var date_arr = date_str.split('.');
var new_date = new Date('20' + date_arr[2], date_arr[1] - 1, date_arr[0]);
console.log(new_date);
```