# Получить возраст пользователя?

Tags: javascript

Нужно определить точный возраст пользователя. поэтому сначала перевожу все в миллисекунды. Но показывает неверный год и возраст соответственно. В чем ошибка?

```
const today = +new Date();
const birthday =  +new Date('01.02.1994');
const diff = today - birthday;
const obj = new Date(diff);
const age = new Date().getFullYear() - obj.getFullYear();
```

Comment: формат даты не тот, используйте запись date через запятые.

Comment: Вопросов похожих много, вот один из  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/666733/%d0%a4%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-date-js

Comment: `new Date('01.02.1994')` => `Sun Jan 02 1994 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (Astrakhan Standard Time)`

Comment: Вместо `+new Date();` можно вызывать `Date.now()`

Comment: все равно не выходит

Comment: Не забудьте что формат даты изменяется в зависимости от настроек клиента, т.е. ваша дата '01.02.1994' не у всех будет корректно переводиться в объект Date

Comment: (Date.now() - new Date('01.02.1994'))/31536000000 это если сколько лет

Answer (score 0):

В javascript объекта Date при преобразовании в Number всегда возвращает UNIX timestamp в миллисекундах (прошедшее кол-во миллисекунда с 1970 года).

Ваш diff это количество миллисекунд прошедшие со дня рождения до текущего времени (не забываем про високосные года).

Затем по этому diff вы получаете дату, т.е. к 1970 году прибавляем diff миллисекунд и получаем тыкву у которой берем год и вычитаем его из текущего года.

Для корректного вычисления возраста лучше работать с количеством дней до текущей даты и количеством дней до дня рождения, а что бы избежать проблем с високосными годами нужно приравнять любой месяц к 31 дням. В итоге получаем примерно такое

```
const today = new Date(); 
const birthday = new Date("01.02.1994");
const todayD = (today.getFullYear()*12 + today.getMonth())*31+today.getDate()-1;
const birthdayD = (birthday.getFullYear()*12 + birthday.getMonth())*31+birthday.getDate()-1;
const age = (todayD - birthdayD)/31/12;
```

Comment: А комментарии почитать? _`const birthday = new Date("01.02.1994");`_ - неверно.

Comment: что-то много кода. а есть еще способы корректно получить возраст  или перевод в миллисекунды?

Comment: @werty я скопировал ваш код, у меня дата будет выглядеть так: new Date("02/01/1994")

Comment: @werty три строки кода по вашему это много? Не пойму для чего вам нужны миллисекунды. Если кратко, то вам в комментарии дали краткий приблизительный ответ (он не точный т.к. не учитывает високосные года)

Comment: хотел перевести все в миллисекунды, вычислить разницу, снова преобразовать объект в Date и получить год. чтобы получить точную разницу

Comment: @werty я же написал почему так делать не стоит - не все года имеют одинаковую продолжительность. Каждый четвертый год больше трех предыдущих на 24 часа (есть исключения).

Comment: а такой вариант с делением на миллисекунды не подойдет?
function getAgeFromBirthday() {
   

    var b_date = new Date(2015, 03, 25);
    
   

    today = new Date();
   


   console.log(Math.floor((today - b_date) / 31556952000));

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yc6mbh5o/
два варианта и все они возвращают 22, хотя должно быть 23